# Docker swarm nginx load balancing not working

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, load, load-balancing

Bear with me as this is a long one.

I have deployed a docker swarm stack for [Wazuh](https://wazuh.com/).

The stack has various services. Amongst them, there is an **nginx** acting as a load balancer between various containers that are listening on port 15147/tcp. In essence, there are server agents (physical or virtual machines, Linux, Mac, Windows, you name it) that register against other service (the Wazuh manager) and exchange information through port 1514/tcp.

So in essence, the agent connects to the nginx lb to port 1514, the lb redirects to one of the workers or the manager and the worker sends the collected data to the manager. The important part here, and what I think is failing, is the load balancing (more below).

This is the compose file (obviously edited to hide actual data):

```
# Wazuh App Copyright (C) 2017, Wazuh Inc. (License GPLv2)
version: '3.8'

services:
  wazuhmaster:
    image: wazuh/wazuh-manager:4.4.0
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    hostname: wazuh.master
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1515:1515"
      - "514:514/udp"
      - "55000:55000"
    environment:
      - INDEXER_URL=https://wazuh1.indexer:9200
      - INDEXER_USERNAME=admin
      - INDEXER_PASSWORD=somerandompassword
      - FILEBEAT_SSL_VERIFICATION_MODE=full
      - SSL_CERTIFICATE_AUTHORITIES=/etc/ssl/root-ca.pem
      - SSL_CERTIFICATE=/etc/ssl/filebeat.pem
      - SSL_KEY=/etc/ssl/filebeat.key
      - API_USERNAME=wazuh-wui
      - API_PASSWORD=anotherrandompassword
    volumes:
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/master-wazuh-api-configuration:/var/ossec/api/configuration
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/master-wazuh-etc:/var/ossec/etc
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/master-wazuh-logs:/var/ossec/logs
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/master-wazuh-queue:/var/ossec/queue
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/master-wazuh-var-multigroups:/var/ossec/var/multigroups
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/master-wazuh-integrations:/var/ossec/integrations
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/master-wazuh-active-response:/var/ossec/active-response/bin
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/master-wazuh-agentless:/var/ossec/agentless
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/master-wazuh-wodles:/var/ossec/wodles
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/master-filebeat-etc:/etc/filebeat
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/master-filebeat-var:/var/lib/filebeat
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/root-ca-manager.pem:/etc/ssl/root-ca.pem
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.master.pem:/etc/ssl/filebeat.pem
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.master-key.pem:/etc/ssl/filebeat.key
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_cluster/wazuh_manager.conf:/wazuh-config-mount/etc/ossec.conf

  wazuhworker:
    image: wazuh/wazuh-manager:4.4.0
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    hostname: wazuh.worker
    restart: always
    environment:
      - INDEXER_URL=https://wazuh1.indexer:9200
      - INDEXER_USERNAME=admin
      - INDEXER_PASSWORD=somerandompassword
      - FILEBEAT_SSL_VERIFICATION_MODE=full
      - SSL_CERTIFICATE_AUTHORITIES=/etc/ssl/root-ca.pem
      - SSL_CERTIFICATE=/etc/ssl/filebeat.pem
      - SSL_KEY=/etc/ssl/filebeat.key
    volumes:
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/worker-wazuh-api-configuration:/var/ossec/api/configuration
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/worker-wazuh-etc:/var/ossec/etc
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/worker-wazuh-logs:/var/ossec/logs
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/worker-wazuh-queue:/var/ossec/queue
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/worker-wazuh-var-multigroups:/var/ossec/var/multigroups
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/worker-wazuh-integrations:/var/ossec/integrations
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/worker-wazuh-active-response:/var/ossec/active-response/bin
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/worker-wazuh-agentless:/var/ossec/agentless
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/worker-wazuh-wodles:/var/ossec/wodles
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/worker-filebeat-etc:/etc/filebeat
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/worker-filebeat-var:/var/lib/filebeat
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/root-ca-manager.pem:/etc/ssl/root-ca.pem
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.worker.pem:/etc/ssl/filebeat.pem
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.worker-key.pem:/etc/ssl/filebeat.key
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_cluster/wazuh_worker.conf:/wazuh-config-mount/etc/ossec.conf

  wazuh1indexer:
    image: wazuh/wazuh-indexer:4.4.0
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    hostname: wazuh1.indexer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    environment:
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      - "bootstrap.memory_lock=true"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/wazuh-indexer-data-1:/var/lib/wazuh-indexer
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/root-ca.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/certs/root-ca.pem
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh1.indexer-key.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/certs/wazuh1.indexer.key
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh1.indexer.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/certs/wazuh1.indexer.pem
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/admin.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/certs/admin.pem
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/admin-key.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/certs/admin-key.pem
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer/wazuh1.indexer.yml:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/opensearch.yml
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer/internal_users.yml:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/opensearch-security/internal_users.yml

  wazuh2indexer:
    image: wazuh/wazuh-indexer:4.4.0
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    hostname: wazuh2.indexer
    restart: always
    environment:
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      - "bootstrap.memory_lock=true"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/wazuh-indexer-data-2:/var/lib/wazuh-indexer
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/root-ca.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/certs/root-ca.pem
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh2.indexer-key.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/certs/wazuh2.indexer.key
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh2.indexer.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/certs/wazuh2.indexer.pem
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer/wazuh2.indexer.yml:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/opensearch.yml
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer/internal_users.yml:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/opensearch-security/internal_users.yml

  wazuh3indexer:
    image: wazuh/wazuh-indexer:4.4.0
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    hostname: wazuh3.indexer
    restart: always
    environment:
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      - "bootstrap.memory_lock=true"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/wazuh-indexer-data-3:/var/lib/wazuh-indexer
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/root-ca.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/certs/root-ca.pem
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh3.indexer-key.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/certs/wazuh3.indexer.key
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh3.indexer.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/certs/wazuh3.indexer.pem
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer/wazuh3.indexer.yml:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/opensearch.yml
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer/internal_users.yml:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/opensearch-security/internal_users.yml

  wazuhdashboard:
    image: wazuh/wazuh-dashboard:4.4.0
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    hostname: wazuh.dashboard
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6443:5601
    environment:
      - OPENSEARCH_HOSTS="https://wazuh1.indexer:9200"
      - WAZUH_API_URL="https://wazuh.master"
      - API_USERNAME=wazuh-wui
      - API_PASSWORD=anotherrandompassword
    volumes:
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.dashboard.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/certs/wazuh-dashboard.pem
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.dashboard-key.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/certs/wazuh-dashboard-key.pem
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/root-ca.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/certs/root-ca.pem
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_dashboard/opensearch_dashboards.yml:/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/config/opensearch_dashboards.yml
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/wazuh_dashboard/wazuh.yml:/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/data/wazuh/config/wazuh.yml
    depends_on:
      - wazuh1indexer
    links:
      - wazuh1.indexer:wazuh1.indexer
      - wazuh.master:wazuh.master

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    hostname: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1514:1514"
    depends_on:
      - wazuhmaster
      - wazuhworker
      - wazuhdashboard
    links:
      - wazuh.master:wazuh.master
      - wazuh.worker:wazuh.worker
      - wazuh.dashboard:wazuh.dashboard
    volumes:
      - /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
```

The important part here is the nginx (the last service). As you can see, nginx takes its configuration from /clustervolumes/volume1/wazuh/config/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf, this is the content:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server_tokens off;
    gzip  on;

}



# load balancer for Wazuh cluster
stream {
    upstream mycluster {
        hash $remote_addr consistent;
        server wazuh.master:1514;
        server wazuh.worker:1514;
    }
    server {
        listen 1514;
        proxy_pass mycluster;
    }
}
```

As you can see here, the nginx shall be balancing between the master and (one of the) workers.

Well, that is not working.

The agents first register against the manager (1515/tcp port) succesfully but when communication shall be established for the actual data (1514/tcp port) something is amiss. This is the nginx log (hostname edited for security reasons):

```
wazuh_nginx.1.y469rcidrlz8f1q9glpd88hik@dockernodehostname    | 2023/05/04 07:47:13 [warn] 30#30: *19525 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: 0.0.0.0:1514, upstream: "10.0.8.11:1514", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
wazuh_nginx.1.y469rcidrlz8f1q9glpd88hik@dockernodehostname    | 2023/05/04 07:47:23 [error] 30#30: *19531 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: 0.0.0.0:1514, upstream: "mycluster", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
wazuh_nginx.1.y469rcidrlz8f1q9glpd88hik@dockernodehostname    | 2023/05/04 07:47:26 [error] 30#30: *19529 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: 0.0.0.0:1514, upstream: "10.0.8.20:1514", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
wazuh_nginx.1.y469rcidrlz8f1q9glpd88hik@dockernodehostname    | 2023/05/04 07:47:26 [warn] 30#30: *19529 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: 0.0.0.0:1514, upstream: "10.0.8.20:1514", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
wazuh_nginx.1.y469rcidrlz8f1q9glpd88hik@dockernodehostname    | 2023/05/04 07:47:29 [error] 30#30: *19529 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: 0.0.0.0:1514, upstream: "10.0.8.11:1514", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
wazuh_nginx.1.y469rcidrlz8f1q9glpd88hik@dockernodehostname    | 2023/05/04 07:47:29 [warn] 30#30: *19529 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: 0.0.0.0:1514, upstream: "10.0.8.11:1514", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
wazuh_nginx.1.y469rcidrlz8f1q9glpd88hik@dockernodehostname    | 2023/05/04 07:47:33 [error] 30#30: *19533 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: 0.0.0.0:1514, upstream: "mycluster", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
wazuh_nginx.1.y469rcidrlz8f1q9glpd88hik@dockernodehostname    | 2023/05/04 07:47:42 [error] 30#30: *19534 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: 0.0.0.0:1514, upstream: "10.0.8.20:1514", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
wazuh_nginx.1.y469rcidrlz8f1q9glpd88hik@dockernodehostname    | 2023/05/04 07:47:42 [warn] 30#30: *19534 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: 0.0.0.0:1514, upstream: "10.0.8.20:1514", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
wazuh_nginx.1.y469rcidrlz8f1q9glpd88hik@dockernodehostname    | 2023/05/04 07:47:43 [error] 30#30: *19537 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: 0.0.0.0:1514, upstream: "mycluster", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
```

So this is what puzzles me, and honestly I have no idea on how to go forward on this.

Help will be really appreciated.

Thanks!